# Change help message when select change

Tags: php, symfony

I have a little symfony form with a select field inside.

```
$builder
    ->add('automaticPaymentMethod', EnumType::class, [
        'class' => AutomaticPaymentMethod::class,
        'horizontal' => false,
        'label_render' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'global',
        'prefix_label_with_class' => true,
    ])
;
```

Working with this enum class

```
final class AutomaticPaymentMethod extends AbstractEnum
{
    const NONE = 'none';
    const CREDIT_CARD = 'card';
    const BANK_ACCOUNT = 'bank';
}
```

I'm trying to change the value of help_block` option with a translated message from my translation files, when the selected value change.

I tried with `EventListener` and `EventSubscriber` but this don't work when the select change.

How can I do this ? Should I use ajax to change this message or php is good enough ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To control the select field change you must to do by javascript, in other case, you must to load all the form, if i had to do this, i put the translations of the help block in data attributes in the select and show this based on the select value. For example:

```
<select>
  <option value="1" data-help-block="{{ 'help block 1'|trans() }}"/>
  <option value="2" data-help-block="{{ 'help block 2'|trans() }}"/>
</select>
```

And update the help block according the selected value